# Why is the performance between two systems with the same SSD so different?

Tags: ssd

Here is a screenshot of a 256GB Samsung 840 Pro:

[image]

The system on right seems to be:

```
Intel Core i5-2400
Intel DH67GD
8GB 1600MHz CL9 DDR3
```

The system on the left is PowerEdge R730 with a Windows Server 2012 R2 standard running inside Windows Server 2012 R2's Hyper-V and it has a DELL PERC H730 and two Xeon processors. The virtual machine itself has 32GB of RAM, and 8 virtual processors.

Why is there such a huge gap in performance different between both machines? What should I look at?

Comment: Performance will be affected by hardware and operating system. Also it may be degraded further if using virtual machine. Another point to be noted is that Samsung SSD performance degrade over time. This is a known issue. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2887255/samsung-promises-yet-another-fix-for-slowed-840-evo-ssds.html

Comment: Both are connected to SATA III ports I presume?  Why can't you tell us, if you want an answer, we need that information.

Comment: Im sure the one on the right is connected to SATA III. That R730 has SAS ports which Im not sure at what speed it is at.

Comment: Im sure the one on the right is connected to SATA III. Seeing that this is a 2015 server, Im pretty sure this is a SAS-3 (12 Gbit/s). That R730 has SAS ports which Im not sure at what speed it is at.

Comment: Anyone have ideas on what to start looking at?

Comment: Searched and I was able to get some information on the system on the right.

Comment: It is quite possible that server SAS ports will fall back to the  SATA-1 standard even if the SATA disk attached is SATA-3 capable. I've  got the same issue with some HP workstations (server-grade motherboards) that can't get full performance out of SATA-2/3 drives.

Comment: @Tonny That seems to be a BIOS issue, don't you think? Is there a way to force all ports at SATA-3? I remember vaguelly something...

Comment: I turned on a setting via iDRAC that is translated literally into "Read Ahead" and it slightly did improve all numbers all around but still nowhere close. What settings should be fine tuned in the BIOS?

Comment: @riahc4 Bios issue, but not adjustable. The SAS BIOS is hardcoded to operate that way. (For no good reason. The SAS-controller chipset itself is SATA-3 capable and in other motherboards with the same chipset will do SATA-3.)

Comment: Looking around the web interface, I can confirm that it 12.0 Gbps @Tonny Would Windows see the drives as "SATA1" as you put it if they are falling back?

Comment: @riahc4 On my systems it does. (Win7, Win8 and Server2012) Can't get more than 1.5 Gb/s out of them. But loss due to Hyper-V getting in the way seesm more likely for your setup.

Answer (score 1):

Im still looking around for information but some have caught my eye and might help you too @Tonny.

It seems that the controller PERC H730 Mini is perfectly ready for SAS-3 (12) BUT I have two SAS drives ST600MM0006 (RAID1) and four SAS drives ST2000NM0023 (RAID5) and they seem to go only up to SAS-2 (6). It could be that the controller itself then falls back everything to SAS-2. The iDRAC tells me that all drives are just hitting SAS-2 while it reports that the controller itself can hit SAS-3.

BTW, after enabling that "Read Ahead" Im hitting this:

[image]

Intrestingly, I changed to passthrough and Im getting slightly worst performance then after enabling "Read Ahead":

[image]

My last test would be passthrough on SCSI controller. It is on a IDE controller because RemoteFX isnt compatible.
Sadly I cannot get it to boot off a passthough SSD attached to a SCSI controller in Windows Server 2012 R2's Hyper-V. Limitation?

Well the best I can do is boot off a VHDX on a IDE controller and passthrough the SSD to a SCSI controller. These are the results:

[image]

Intresting results. Write speeds improve and read speeds SLIGHTLY go down.

Another test

I directly attached the SSD to the Hyper-V host and then ran CrystalDiskMark on the actual Hyper-V host (no virtualization)

[image]

Speeds are not that impressive so I would tend to start to believe that the issue is the controller (or its driver).

Comment: That wouldn't explain the terrible write performance.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit: It wouldnt explain much at all.

Comment: Hyper-V generally seems to have poor disk write performance especially for virtual disks, I think that is likely to be a factor.

Comment: Well, I was going to that next: Do a passthough of the drive directly thru to the virutal machine and boot off that. This way Hyper-V is barely involved.

Comment: More comments and tests added.